# Difference between nested if (condition) and logical operator

Tags: performance, if-statement, logic, operator-keyword, logical-operators

What is difference between nested if (condition) and logical operator in terms of performance and logic.

```
if(a && b && c){
 //do something 
 }

if(a){
   if(b){
         if(c){
       //do something
     }
   }
 }
```

Are the above codes same logic wise?
My main concern is performance of the code, performance wise which is the best to use ?

Answer (score 0):

If you try to convert those two codes into `assembly` language (which is very close to machine language), both codes will converted exactly the same ([first code](https://godbolt.org/z/e8azbo), [second code](https://godbolt.org/z/q_NOeg)):

**C**:

```
void Main(){
    int a=1, b=2, c= 3, res = 0;

    if(a && b && c)
        res = 100;
}

// or
void Main(){
    int a=1, b=2, c= 3, res = 0;

    if(a)
        if(b)
            if(c)
                res = 100;
}
```

**Assembly Output**:

```
Main():
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 1
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], 2
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-12], 3
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-16], 0
        cmp     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 0
        je      .L3                     ; jump to the end if `a` is not true
        cmp     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], 0
        je      .L3                     ; jump to the end if `b` is not true
        cmp     DWORD PTR [rbp-12], 0
        je      .L3                     ; jump to the end if `c` is not true
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-16], 100 ; otherwise do something
.L3:
        nop
        pop     rbp
        ret
```